If $f(x)$ has period $T$ and $g(x)$ has period $t$, then show that $f(x)+g(x)$ can be periodic even if LCM of $(T,t)$ does not exist
The question- If $f(x)$ has period $T$ and $g(x)$ has period $t$, then show that $f(x)+g(x)$ can be periodic even if LCM of $(T,t)$ does not exist. ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non constant).
My view- I realised that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ cannot be continuous, hence they must be distributed in parts, what I seek is an example to show that $f(x) + g(x)$ is periodic (By example , I mean a rough sketch of graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$)

What is the LCM of two numbers if one of those is not an integer?

@mathcounterexamples.net $t\mathbb{Z} \cap T\mathbb{Z} = \text{LCM}(t,T)\mathbb{Z}$

What is $LCM(t,T)$ when for example $t=2, T= \sqrt 2$?

Can be or must be?

Should be "can be". Normally one would execpt the sum of 2 functions with noncommensurable periods to be not periodic.

A possible answer is finding a non-constant function $f$ that has 2 periods with non-rational quotient. An example, which can easily be expanded, is to define
$$A = \{x \in \mathbb R: \exists a,b \in \mathbb Q,\, x=a+b\sqrt{2}\};\; B = \mathbb R\backslash A.$$
We get that $A$ is not empty, but has a countable cardinality, so $B$ must be non-empty as well.
If we set
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \in A,\\
1 & \text{ if } x \in B\\
\end{cases}$$
then it's easy to see that this $f$ has both period $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$, in fact, any positive rational multiple of either is a period.
If we now take any function with period $1$, say $g(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$,
then $f(x)$ has period $\sqrt{2}$, $g(x)$ has period $1$ and $f(x)+g(x)$ has period $1$ as well, as it is a common period of both $f$ and $g$.
This gives an example as required by the question.
Of course, it feals a bit like cheating, constructing $f$ and $g$ to have a common period. I'll have to think more about a solution without that property.
